# Create serial number column in telerik mvc grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I could create a grid with telerik mvc

```
<% Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("ProductGrid")
    .Columns(columns => { 
                        columns.Bound(h => h.ProductName).Width("34%");
                        columns.Bound(h => h.Description).Width("60%");
                        columns.Bound(h => h.ProductID).Format(Html.ImageLink("Edit", "Products", new { Id = "{0}" }, "/Content/images/icon_edit.gif", "", new { Id = "edit{0}" }, null).ToString()).Encoded(false).Title("").Sortable(false).Width("3%");
                        columns.Bound(h => h.ProductID).Format(Html.ImageLink("Delete", "Products", new { Id = "{0}" }, "/Content/images/icon_delete.gif", "", new { onclick = string.Format("return confirm('Are you sure to delete this add on?');") },null).ToString()).Encoded(false).Title("").Sortable(false).Width("3%");
        })

    .EnableCustomBinding(true)
    .DataBinding(databinding => databinding.Ajax().Select("_Index", "ProductGrid"))
    .Pageable(settings => settings.Total((int)ViewData["TotalPages"])
    .PageSize(10))
    .Sortable()
    .Render(); %>
```

but I need to add a serial number column in telerik grid.How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is to add a SerialNumber column to your Product class which is your model and than just add another bound column to the grid like this:

```
columns.Bound(h => h.SerialNumber)
```

If you pass a List of Products you can populate the SerialNumber column like this:

```
List<Product> products = GetList(); // Your method to get data here
int counter = 1;
products.ForEach(x => x.SerialNumber = counter++);
```

If you want to support consistent numbers with paging you have to calculate yourself the initial value of the `counter` valuable. For this purpose you must have the current page and page size.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.If Iam adding a property "SerialNumber" in "Product" class.How can I increment its value for each row?

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way is to use template column like this.

```
<% 
    var sn = 0;
    Html.Telerik().Grid(Model).Name("Grid").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:auto" })
        .EnableCustomBinding(true)
        .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Template(c=> {%> <%: ++sn %> <% }).Title("S/N");
                        columns.Bound(c => c.CustomerNumber);
                        columns.Bound(c => c.Narration);
                    })
                    .Render();  %>
```

This way you don't have to be adding serial number property to your view models.

Hope this help?

Answer (score -1):

In MVC Web Grid 
use this calculation

```
 grid.Column(header: "#",
   format: item => item.WebGrid.Rows.IndexOf(item) + 1 + Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(grid.TotalRowCount / grid.PageCount) / grid.RowsPerPage) * grid.RowsPerPage * grid.PageIndex),
```